# What is the meaning of "ENT1 *" in TAOCP MIX assembly language?

Tags: assembly, knuth, taocp

In the book *The Art of Computer Programming Volume 1, third edition*, I'm having some hard time understanding the meaning of the following MIX assembly language instruction: `ENT1 *`, which appears on page 189 of the book.

> (p.189) For example, if we wanted to make the calling sequence for `MAXN` be
>
> ```
>      JMP  MAXN
>      CON  n
> ```
>
> then the subroutine could be written as follows:
>
> ```
> MAXN STJ  *+1
>      ENT1 *
> ```

What I've figured out so far is that the following line

```
MAXN STJ  *+1
```

stores the address of the memory where the constant `n` is stored to the [0:2] field of the memory location where the instruction `ENT1 *` is stored.

Therefore, I'm guessing here that the following line

```
     ENT1 *
```

is supposed to load the value of [0:2] field of the memory location where the instruction `ENT1 *` is stored to register `I1`.

However, the meaning of asterisk(`*`), as stated in the text book is:

> (p.146) An asterisk (read "self") refers to the location of the line on which it appears.

So, shouldn't  `ENT1 *` just store the address of the memory location where the  instruction `ENT1 *` is stored to register `I1`?

Comment: Have you tried assembling it with `mixal` and looking at the hexdump of the machine code?  I don't know MIX but was curious.  I got as far as finding `ENTi` documented at https://www.gnu.org/software/mdk/manual/html_node/Address-transfer-operators.html.  (And that MIX uses 6-bit bytes with 5-byte words... Interesting. 
 No wonder Knuth is replacing it with MMIX, a RISC machine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short Answer

The point that I missed was that the asterisk(`*`) being the value of the current location is worth acknowledging only at the time of *assembling*. Since MIX is an assembly language that *modifies the instruction itself*, **the value that is stored in the `I1` register is determined at run-time**.

So in this case, the asterisk(`*`) in `ENT1 *` has no meanings. It is even possible to change `*` to *any* value, since the value that is stored in the `I1` register will be determined by the previous instruction: `STJ  *+1`.

#### Verification with MIX Builder

I've assembled the following MIX assembly language code with `MIX Builder` on Windows 10 downloaded from [here](http://www.menees.com/MIXBuilder.htm).

```
      ORIG 3000
BEGIN JMP  MAXN
      CON  100
MAXN  STJ  *+1
      ENT1 *
      LD3  0,1
      HLT
      END  BEGIN
```

After assembling, the result is:

[image]

We can check that the instruction in line 5, `ENT1 *`, has the current memory location `3003` stored on the [0:2] field.

After executing line 4, the [0:2] field of line 5 changes to `3001`, the memory location where the constant `100` is stored:

[image]

Therefore, after executin line 5, the value `3001` (not `3003`) will be stored in the `I1` register:

[image]

Note that combining the byte values `46` and `57` in the `I1` register results in `3001(= 46 * 64 + 57)`, i.e. they are base 64 values.